# Fancybox doesn't trigger on $(elem).click(), but does on "real" click?

Tags: jquery, triggers, click, fancybox

I'm having trouble getting fancybox to trigger. I have it set up to trigger when you click an element. I still don't know *why*, but for some reason fancybox only works if i bind it using `live()`, sort of like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This works
    $('.fancybox').live('mousedown', function() {
        $(this).fancybox();
    });

    // This doesn't
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
```

Read more about that here:
[Fancybox is loaded, but nothing happens, and no errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458123/fancybox-is-loaded-but-nothing-happens-and-no-errors)

The problem is, it only works if i actually click the element. If i try to trigger a click using:

```
$('.fancybox').trigger('mousedown');
```

i get nothing! It just doesn't work.

The reason i need to do this is because the images are being printed out with PHP in a gallery (with thumbnails etc). I only want a dropdown of the available galleries, so on page load, i hide all of the thumbnails and then loop through them and create a dropdown menu containing all the galleries. So far so good! If i show the element using the inspector (using chrome) and then manually click on it, it works fine! Although, the problem is, when i try to trigger the click using the dropdown, nothing happens!

I have it set up so that every `<option>` in the dropdown has a data attribute of the gallery/thumbnail ID, and when the dropdown changes (when you select an option), it automatically finds the correct image, and triggers a click - which in turn should open a fancybox. I know it finds the correct image, and clicks it, it's just that nothing happens when it's clicked.

Try it!

URL: http://goo.gl/r4Klf

Rightclick on the first dropdown menu in the content, and inspect it. Above it, you'll see a bunch of `.ngg-galleryoverview` elements. Click on one of them and remove all the styling applied to the element (in element.style, the style basically hides the element). Then expand the element, and in there you'll see a `.ngg-gallery-thumbnail`. Remove `display: none` from the styling. You should now be able to see the element on the page. If you try clicking it, the fancybox will open. However, if you try to click it using `$(the element).trigger('mousedown')`, it's not going to work. Try targeting it using the href attribute, something like:

```
jQuery('a[href="http://hallarna.se/wp-content/gallery/2013/spoksonatenloggaliten.jpg"]').trigger('mousedown');
```

Please do note that jQuery is in noConflict mode meaning you will have to use jQuery() instead of $().

I've been battling this for several days now. Any ideas are super appreciated!

Comment: don't know if this could be of any help, but jQuery('#ngg-image-207 a').trigger('click'); works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see where the problem is. When you trigger mousedown, it just fires the plugin to work with the specified element when you click it; it's not actually supposed to show anything... until you click it or you trigger the click.

Try something like

```
jQuery('a[href="http://hallarna.se/wp-content/gallery/2013/spoksonatenloggaliten.jpg"]').trigger('mousedown').trigger('click');
```

Although I would look for a solution to make fancybox work as intended, with $('.fancybox').fancybox();

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. I still struggle to get it to work from my script, though it seems to work from the console. I'll see if i can get it to work, or i might just use an alternative to fancybox. Thanks for the help!

Comment: FYI i ended up switching to colorbox, which was implemented flawlessly. There are some drawbacks though, it's not responsive, and it doesn't have as much options as fancybox - but at least it works. I'll mark your answer as accepted because you did point out why it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @qwerty : I don't think the problem is fancybox but the way you were trying to use it. You seem confused about the implementation. This `$('.fancybox').fancybox();` doesn't (and will never do) trigger fancybox ... it just binds fancybox to the selector `.fancybox` but still needs a click on the selector to fire it... you could have done `$('.fancybox').fancybox().trigger('click')` to force the `click` without `live` in any case.

Comment: Yes, i am well aware of that! Please read the following question (also linked from the OP) and you'll understand why i wasn't able to bind it normally. And, because i used the approach i had to use above (binding it on mousedown with live), i sometimes had to click it twice to work. Either way, the problem was not how i implemented it but rather that it didn't bind correctly. Here's a a tiny codepen demonstrating how i tried binding it (the correct way) without success: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jotmn (taken from the other link)